# Parametrize 1-Manifold?

Tags: manifolds, galois-theory, differential-topology

In our calculus textbook, it claims without proof that the polynomial function $f(x) = x^3+x$, which is a bijection of the real line with itself, has no closed-form inverse function.

What would be two odd degree, degree 5 or higher monic polynomials $p(x) \ne q(x)$ with rational coefficients with everywhere positive derivative, Galois group that is not solvable (so they are truly bijections of the real line with no elementary inverse functions), and which do not commute?

If such polynomials exist and forming the 1-manifold $C$ by $p(x) = q(y)$ in the plane, what would be an elementary parametrization of $C$ or some subarc thereof? Is there some canonical way to parametrize $C$? Just choosing $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma(t) = (q(t),p(t))$ won't work, because $p$ and $q$ don't commute, nor will choosing $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma(t) = (t,(q^{-1} \circ p)(t))$ or $\gamma(t) = ((p^{-1} \circ q)(t),t)$, as $p^{-1}$ and $q^{-1}$ are non-elementary.

Comment: If a curve $C$ can be parametrized as $x=r(t)$, $y=s(t)$ with rational functions of a parameter $t$ (i.e. quotients of polynomials of $t$), then the curve (or, more precisely, a smooth model of its function field) has genus zero. The genus of a smooth plane curve of degree $n$ is $g=(n-1)(n-2)/2$. So if the degree is $n\ge3$ then either the curve is not smooth or it has no rational parametrization.

Comment: (cont'd) Well known cubic curves having such a parametrization include the alpha curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$, parametrized by $x=t+1$, $y=t(t+1)$, and the folium $x^3+y^3=3xy$ parametrized by $x=3t/(1+t^3)$, $y=3t^2/(1+t^3)$ both have a singularity at the origin, so they still have genus zero in spite of being cubic.

Comment: (cont'd) More often than not $p(x)=q(y)$ defines a smooth curve, so we should not expect simple parametrizations. In the cubic case of $g=1$ we have elliptic curves, parametrized (in the complex domain) by Weierstrass $\wp$-function and its derivative.

Comment: I'm aware that my comments may not be very helpful. That's why they are comments only. The point, if any, was to explain that in most cases we can rule out the possibility of a rational parametrization. Asking for a small arc only won't change that fact because a small arc would already be Zariski dense on $C$.